# What are the limitations of WebVR video player compared to native app?

Tags: webvr

Trying to figure out what are the limitations of WebVR compared to native player.

The first comes with browser's engine limited to process high performance VR videos.

The second comes with browser's support of VR engine. Not everything on VR engine could be implemented for browser and if it could some time is required to put it there and have it released (here comes delay in updates coming on WebVR).

Any thoughts on that?